# Kammatz katan in Kaddish

Tags: grammar-dikduk, kaddish

In the Kaddish, the words בעלמא, לעלם, ולעלמי, עלמיא are all related to the Hebrew word עולם, from which I conclude that in each of those four words, the kammatz vowel below the ע is a kammatz katan as it is a shortened form of cholam. Therefore, when Kaddish is recited in a synagogue where the prayers are pronounced in sefaradit, they should all be pronounced "o" as in כָּל. Is that correct?

Comment: They are Aramaic words, not Hebrew, so you can't directly apply the same rules.

Comment: That is true in principle, but in practice, every published siddur that I have seen treats the prayers that are in Aramaic as though the rules of Hebrew grammar affecting pronunciation apply to those prayers. You see that in the application of nikkud to them including the marks (in siddurim that use them) that distinguish between shva na and shva nach. In any case, my question was predicated on the assumption (whether true or not) that the grammar rules that apply are the rules of Hebrew grammar